# Define backing bean in one JSF app into another JSF app

Tags: jsf, richfaces, jsf-1.2

I have an EAR which will contain multiple JSF 1.2 + RF 3.3.(0/3) WARs.

The requirement is that I need to invoke a method in one WAR from another WAR. Its sure that both of them are JSF applications.

So is it possible to declare a bean in one WAR into faces-config of another WAR but both WARs residing in one EAR?

Or is there a better alternative for this work?

========edit======================================================

Or to make the problem more simple/complex : another scenario why this question came up is,

I am trying to invoke one application screen from another app.

Ex : Invoking app is invoke.war and invoked app is target.war .

If I directly access target.war it has 1st screen which process the data and moves to second screen.

But If I have to invoke target.war from invoke.war, I already process the data (in invoke.war) and so want to go directly to second screen, so that target.war does not have to process again.

For this I thought of above approach :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to directly call methods in a backing bean in another WAR. Here are a few alternative approaches:

1. Expose the methods in the "other WAR" using something like Remote EJBs or SOAP/REST services.
2. Store the data in a cache that is visible to both WARs. If you use JBoss, then JBoss Cache could meet your needs.
3. Enable session-sharing, and store the data in the session. Not all app servers support this; I know WebSphere does.

Comment: Yes, what you suggested are the only ways I could imagine for this purpose.